# How to install AMD drivers for A10 7870k APU

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati

How do I install the driver from here? Can you guide me through it step-by-step? Much appreciated!

[image: Files]

Comment: Where did you get this deb files from?

Comment: Downloaded the driver and extracted...

Comment: Where did you download it from and how did you extract it?

Comment: And why don't you install the driver a normal way?

Comment: And what is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: You can install downloaded .deb packages by double clicking, but be carefull there, as some of them seem to be for 12.04.4, and others for 14.04. With that out of the way, I'd strongly recommend using the built in program that you have open in the Launcher.

Answer (score 0):

If your system is Ubuntu 14.04, you can install the drivers by typing in terminal

```
cd ~/Downloads/AMD-A10
```

press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx*14*.deb
```

press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

But you do not need `dev` packages.

Comment: Which file do I install specifically?

Comment: `fglrx` and `fglrx-cccle` for 14.04.